# Use Entity Framework 6 Migrations with SqlConnection with AccessToken

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations, sqlconnection

I am trying to use EntityFramework 6 Migrations in conjunction with Azure Databases. I am using a SqlConnection with AccessToken to Connect to the Azure Database and Migrate.

```
public class MasterDbContext : DbContext
{
    //...

    public MasterDbContext(SqlConnection connection)
        : base(connection,true)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MasterDbContext, Migrations.Configuration>(true));
    }

    //...


}            

public async Task SeedMasterDatabaseAsync(string connectionString)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    {
        AccessToken = "xyc"
    };

    using (var dbcontext = new MasterDbContext(conn))
    {
        dbcontext.Database.Initialize(false);
    }
}
```

I am receiving the followoing exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''.
```

The exception message implies that the DBMigrator is not useing the SQL Connection but tries to create a new Connection from the Connectionstring.

This is my Connectionstring:

```
<add name="MasterDbContext" connectionString="Server=foo;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The question is, are AccessToken supported in EF6.3 Migrations in conjunction with Azure Databases? Or is this an permission Issue on master database? Any workaround if AccessToken are a mandatory requirement?

Comment: I am guessing permission issue on master